# Why does gradle project creation take SO LONG with eclipse STS plugin?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I just installed a brand new `eclipse mars` and `Spring Tool Suite 3.7.1`. And I started with an empty workspace.

I create a gradle project as below:

[image]

But it seems to take forever to `Create Gradle project..` as below:

[image]

Even I force to exit eclipse, it remains there and block the eclipse from exiting. As below:

[image]

I have to kill it with task manager.

Why is it so difficult to create a simple gradle project?

### ADD 1

Just see this, it seems working.
https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/

Answer (score 2):

It takes a long time the first time because all the dependencies are being downloaded to local cache as part of the project setup. Just be patient it should complete eventually (unless there's something preventing gradle from accessing the internet).

The second project you create should be a lot faster as all the dependencies will already be locally cached.

Answer (score 1):

If it already took too much time during the build. Then probably everything got downloaded. Just try switching off the internet during import. That worked for me...